# web scraping understat website to retrieve table failing in R

Tags: html, r, xml, screen-scraping

I am trying to to pull out a table from the the website https://understat.com/league/EPL

The table I am trying to import into R is highlighted in red in the screenshot here;
[screenshot of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHM4r.png)

Using inspect tools I can see the xpath to the table as follows;

```
//*[@id="league-chemp"]/table
```

full XPath is

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/table
```

My code is as follows;

```
library(rvest)
library(selectr)
library(xml2)
library(jsonlite)
library(htmltab)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url <- 'https://understat.com/league/EPL'

webpage <- read_html('https://understat.com/league/EPL')

xpath <- "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody"

nodes <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath = xpath)
```

However the response is;

```
> nodes
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

I've hit a dead end, I think there maybe some embedded JSON code and javascript within the main html body of the response that is causing issues, but its all above my expertise right now.

Comment: It seems the table is not html but a java script and rvest can't help much here. You might want to look into Rselenium or similar packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract the table with the following code :

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = port)
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()

url <- "https://understat.com/league/EPL"
remDr$navigate(url)

Sys.sleep(5)
html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
tables <- read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table()
tables

[[1]]
# A tibble: 20 x 12
     `<U+2116>` Team                        M     W     D     L     G    GA   PTS xG         xGA        xPTS      
   <int> <chr>                   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
 1     1 Arsenal                     9     8     0     1    23    10    24 19.48-3.52 8.17-1.83  20.03-3.97
 2     2 Manchester City             9     7     2     0    33     9    23 23.27-9.73 5.81-3.19  23.59+0.59
 3     3 Tottenham                   9     6     2     1    20    10    20 14.78-5.22 10.60+0.60 15.12-4.88
 4     4 Chelsea                     8     5     1     2    13    10    16 12.10-0.90 10.62+0.62 11.86-4.14
 5     5 Manchester United           8     5     0     3    13    15    15 12.35-0.65 11.41-3.59 11.86-3.14
 6     6 Newcastle United            9     3     5     1    17     9    14 18.41+1.41 12.13+3.13 15.73+1.73
 7     7 Brighton                    8     4     2     2    14     9    14 14.52+0.52 8.58-0.42  15.53+1.53
 8     8 Bournemouth                 9     3     3     3     8    20    12 5.26-2.74  15.39-4.61 6.43-5.57 
 9     9 Fulham                      9     3     2     4    14    18    11 10.22-3.78 21.34+3.34 7.02-3.98 
10    10 Liverpool                   8     2     4     2    20    12    10 17.02-2.98 12.33+0.33 12.95+2.95
11    11 Brentford                   9     2     4     3    16    17    10 13.28-2.72 13.00-4.00 12.78+2.78
12    12 Everton                     9     2     4     3     8     9    10 10.33+2.33 14.67+5.67 9.13-0.87 
13    13 West Ham                    9     3     1     5     8    10    10 11.51+3.51 9.64-0.36  13.64+3.64
14    14 Leeds                       8     2     3     3    11    12     9 10.45-0.55 12.28+0.28 9.73+0.73 
15    15 Crystal Palace              8     2     3     3    10    12     9 9.91-0.09  13.71+1.71 8.62-0.38 
16    16 Aston Villa                 8     2     2     4     6    10     8 8.08+2.08  10.45+0.45 10.24+2.24
17    17 Southampton                 9     2     1     6     8    17     7 9.32+1.32  13.88-3.12 9.36+2.36 
18    18 Wolverhampton Wanderers     9     1     3     5     3    12     6 8.16+5.16  11.84-0.16 9.54+3.54 
19    19 Leicester                   9     1     1     7    15    24     4 9.06-5.94  15.12-8.88 8.00+4.00 
20    20 Nottingham Forest           8     1     1     6     6    21     4 8.62+2.62  15.17-5.83 7.48+3.48 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 11 x 11
     `<U+2116>` Player                Team               Apps   Min     G     A xG          xA           xG90  xA90
   <int> <chr>                 <chr>             <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>       <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 "Erling Haaland"      "Manchester City"     9   768    15     3 10.10-4.90  2.61-0.39    1.18  0.31
 2     2 "Harry Kane"          "Tottenham"           9   804     8     1 6.72-1.28   2.06+1.06    0.75  0.23
 3     3 "Roberto Firmino"     "Liverpool"           7   473     6     3 4.06-1.94   1.40-1.60    0.77  0.27
 4     4 "Aleksandar Mitrovic" "Fulham"              8   666     6     0 4.53-1.47   0.38+0.38    0.61  0.05
 5     5 "Ivan Toney"          "Brentford"           9   810     6     2 5.24-0.76   1.55-0.45    0.58  0.17
 6     6 "Phil Foden"          "Manchester City"     9   678     6     4 3.37-2.63   2.49-1.51    0.45  0.33
 7     7 "Gabriel Jesus"       "Arsenal"             9   794     5     3 6.29+1.29   1.73-1.27    0.71  0.2 
 8     8 "James Maddison"      "Leicester"           8   716     5     2 1.40-3.60   0.97-1.03    0.18  0.12
 9     9 "Leandro Trossard"    "Brighton"            8   686     5     1 3.01-1.99   0.70-0.30    0.39  0.09
10    10 "Wilfried Zaha"       "Crystal Palace"      7   624     4     1 3.33-0.67   1.24+0.24    0.48  0.18
11    NA ""                    ""                   NA    NA   252   183 250.82-1.18 180.23-2.77 NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

url <- "https://understat.com/league/EPL"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()

html_Content <- doc$Body()$innerHTML()
tables <- read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table()

tables
[[1]]
# A tibble: 20 x 12
     `?` Team                        M     W     D     L     G    GA   PTS xG         xGA        xPTS      
   <int> <chr>                   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
 1     1 Arsenal                     9     8     0     1    23    10    24 19.48-3.52 8.17-1.83  20.03-3.97
 2     2 Manchester City             9     7     2     0    33     9    23 23.27-9.73 5.81-3.19  23.59+0.59
 3     3 Tottenham                   9     6     2     1    20    10    20 14.78-5.22 10.60+0.60 15.12-4.88
 4     4 Chelsea                     8     5     1     2    13    10    16 12.10-0.90 10.62+0.62 11.86-4.14
 5     5 Manchester United           8     5     0     3    13    15    15 12.35-0.65 11.41-3.59 11.86-3.14
 6     6 Newcastle United            9     3     5     1    17     9    14 18.41+1.41 12.13+3.13 15.73+1.73
 7     7 Brighton                    8     4     2     2    14     9    14 14.52+0.52 8.58-0.42  15.53+1.53
 8     8 Bournemouth                 9     3     3     3     8    20    12 5.26-2.74  15.39-4.61 6.43-5.57 
 9     9 Fulham                      9     3     2     4    14    18    11 10.22-3.78 21.34+3.34 7.02-3.98 
10    10 Liverpool                   8     2     4     2    20    12    10 17.02-2.98 12.33+0.33 12.95+2.95
11    11 Brentford                   9     2     4     3    16    17    10 13.28-2.72 13.00-4.00 12.78+2.78
12    12 Everton                     9     2     4     3     8     9    10 10.33+2.33 14.67+5.67 9.13-0.87 
13    13 West Ham                    9     3     1     5     8    10    10 11.51+3.51 9.64-0.36  13.64+3.64
14    14 Leeds                       8     2     3     3    11    12     9 10.45-0.55 12.28+0.28 9.73+0.73 
15    15 Crystal Palace              8     2     3     3    10    12     9 9.91-0.09  13.71+1.71 8.62-0.38 
16    16 Aston Villa                 8     2     2     4     6    10     8 8.08+2.08  10.45+0.45 10.24+2.24
17    17 Southampton                 9     2     1     6     8    17     7 9.32+1.32  13.88-3.12 9.36+2.36 
18    18 Wolverhampton Wanderers     9     1     3     5     3    12     6 8.16+5.16  11.84-0.16 9.54+3.54 
19    19 Leicester                   9     1     1     7    15    24     4 9.06-5.94  15.12-8.88 8.00+4.00 
20    20 Nottingham Forest           8     1     1     6     6    21     4 8.62+2.62  15.17-5.83 7.48+3.48 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 11 x 11
     `?` Player                Team               Apps   Min     G     A xG          xA           xG90  xA90
   <int> <chr>                 <chr>             <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>       <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 "Erling Haaland"      "Manchester City"     9   768    15     3 10.10-4.90  2.61-0.39    1.18  0.31
 2     2 "Harry Kane"          "Tottenham"           9   804     8     1 6.72-1.28   2.06+1.06    0.75  0.23
 3     3 "Roberto Firmino"     "Liverpool"           7   473     6     3 4.06-1.94   1.40-1.60    0.77  0.27
 4     4 "Aleksandar Mitrovic" "Fulham"              8   666     6     0 4.53-1.47   0.38+0.38    0.61  0.05
 5     5 "Ivan Toney"          "Brentford"           9   810     6     2 5.24-0.76   1.55-0.45    0.58  0.17
 6     6 "Phil Foden"          "Manchester City"     9   678     6     4 3.37-2.63   2.49-1.51    0.45  0.33
 7     7 "Gabriel Jesus"       "Arsenal"             9   794     5     3 6.29+1.29   1.73-1.27    0.71  0.2 
 8     8 "James Maddison"      "Leicester"           8   716     5     2 1.40-3.60   0.97-1.03    0.18  0.12
 9     9 "Leandro Trossard"    "Brighton"            8   686     5     1 3.01-1.99   0.70-0.30    0.39  0.09
10    10 "Wilfried Zaha"       "Crystal Palace"      7   624     4     1 3.33-0.67   1.24+0.24    0.48  0.18
11    NA ""                    ""                   NA    NA   252   183 250.82-1.18 180.23-2.77 NA    NA
```